# Printing in python with if else conditions and correct spacing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I couldn't find a proper answer to my question.
So the deal is this: 
I need to print a 2D array, but each cell is a list of size 2. The first value in this list is 'H' or 'S' for hidden or seen. The second is the actual value.
I need to print each line like this: format: ("%-2s %-2s... %-2s"),  what to print: if first value is 'H' print 'H' else print the second value.

Please help me accomplish this task, thank you!

I was trying the next code:

```
    print ' ' , ''.join('%-2s ' % i for i in range(self.gameBoard.width)) 
    for i in range(self.gameBoard.height):
        print '%-2s'%i, ''.join('%-2s ' % v[1] for v in self.gameBoard.Matrix[i] if v[0] == 'S')
```

"i" is for line number.

Comment: Please add code samples.

Comment: Done i added the code i try.

Comment: This code works but prints only the cells with 'S' at the first place, but not the 'H'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution seems to be working, you just need to change the last line from:

```
print '%-2s'%i, ''.join('%-2s ' % v[1] for v in self.gameBoard.Matrix[i] if v[0] == 'S')
```

to:

```
print '%-2s'%i, ''.join('%-2s ' % ((v[1] if v[0] == 'S' else 'H') for v in self.gameBoard.Matrix[i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use enumerate to iterate over the lines directly

```
print ' ' , ''.join('%-2s ' % i for i in range(self.gameBoard.width)) 
for i, row in enumerate(self.gameBoard.Matrix):
    print '%-2s'%i, ''.join('%-2s '%(v[1] if V[0]==S else 'H') for v in row)
```

It's preferred to use `format` instead of `%` formatting

```
print ' ' , ' '.join(format(i, '2') for i in range(self.gameBoard.width)) 
for i, row in enumerate(self.gameBoard.Matrix):
    print '%-2s'%i, ' '.join(format(v[1] if V[0]==S else 'H', '2') for v in row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
$a = [['H',1], ['H',2],['S',3],['H',4], ['S',5]]
$print [k if k=='H' else v for k,v in a]
['H', 'H', 3, 'H', 5]
```